# How to restrict the service to update Activity Textview?

Tags: android

I am working on an application where I have used Intent service to download the data from server and I have used Handler to update an activity.But I have a problem that how to restrict Activity textview being called when I destroy that activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isFinishing()` method of an activity for this.

Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#isFinishing()